# AngularJS search button

Tags: angularjs

Hi I have a form that is searchable when entering in data to textboxes and then clicking a submit button.  It works perfectly the first time through, but when I try to clear out the values and do a second search it starts to display data without a button click.  It does the two-way binding just by typing in the text box.  I need it to only work when the button is clicked.  Here's my code:

HTML

```
<form name="form" id="form" novalidate>
<div>
    <input ng-model="searchModel.address" />
    <input ng-model="searchModel.city" />
    <button type="submit" ng-click="filterSearch = searchModel">Search</button>
    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Address
                </th>
                <th>
                    City
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="search in vm.searches | filter:{'address': filterSearch.address, 'city': filterSearch.city}">
                <td>
                    {{ search.address }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ search.city }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
(function () {   
'use strict'
angular
    .module('crm.ma')
    .controller('AdvancedSearchCtrl', AdvancedSearchCtrl);

function AdvancedSearchCtrl() {
    var vm = this;       

    vm.searches = [
               {
                   "address": "202 This St",
                   "city": "Columbus"
               },
               {
                   "address": "205 That St",
                   "city": "Dayton"
               }

    ];

}

vm.SearchModel = function () {
    var vm = this;
    vm.filterSearch = angular.copy(searchModel);
};
})();
```

Comment: Your `ng-click` just does a reference assignment.  Did you mean to do something like `ng-click="SearchModel();"` which actually does the deep copy?

Comment: @ryanyuyu when I do that the search button doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out.

HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">Search</div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <input id="address" ng-model="vm.searchModel.address" />
            <input id="city" ng-model="vm.searchModel.city" />               
            <button type="submit" ng-click="vm.search()" data-dismiss="modal">Search</button>
            <button type="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
 <div>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Address
            </th>
            <th>
                City
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="search in vm.filteredSearch">
            <td>
                {{ search.address }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ search.city }}
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
(function () {   
'use strict'
angular
    .module('crm.ma')
   .controller('AdvancedSearchCtrl', function ($scope, $filter) {

       var vm = this;

       vm.searches = [
                  {
                      "address": "202 This St",
                      "city": "Columbus"

                  },
                  {
                      "address": "205 That St",
                      "city": "Erlanger"                          
                  }

       ];
       vm.filteredSearch = vm.searches
       vm.searchModel = {};
       vm.search = function () {
           vm.filteredSearch = $filter('filter')(vm.searches, { 'address': vm.searchModel.address, 'city': vm.searchModel.city });
       }
   });

})();
```